# Dataweave stopped picking up Java linkedList data from query in input payload side

Tags: java, mule

I created a query **"select * from auto_policy;"** in Database component. It showed the data from Java `LinkedList` in the `Dataweave` component (Mule) and I mapped to a huge `CDM XSD` on the output side. I had an issue with the database missing things and having extra fields I didn't need. I modified the table in the database. I spent hours trying to get the metadata(showing) to show the new columns. Finally I scrapped everything and tried a brand new project.

Now, I cannot get the same query **"select * or written out columns from auto_policy;"** (includes the semicolon) to show anything on the left side (input) of the `Dataweave` component. Stumped here in NC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your *Database* connector properties, and make sure:

1. It is connected successfully to the database
2. The metadata (columns name) is listed in the Output tab as Payload

If not listed there (or not updated, e.g.: only 5 columns, whereas it should be 7) then click Refresh Metadata link at the bottom.

[image]

Once you get the expected metadata, then it will be listed on the left side (input) of the *DataWeave* component.

[image]

Comment: where is your screenshot coming from? I have seen the payload, flow vars, session vars, inbound props, outbound props, etc. all in the Dataweave window when you double-click the Transform Message component. I have NOT seen the "Refresh Metadata" at the bottom like that.

Comment: Double click the Database connector, and it will show its properties. Look at on the right side of the properties window.

Comment: Excellent, this worked perfectly. Unknown and then click "Refresh Metadata" and then payload List<Map> .. Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the database is not connected. just check the connectivity for the data base. And when you keep dataweave after database it will fetch all the required fields directly and when you provide the output side metadata make sure its added correctly. Map the fields as per your requirement.

Comment: See my comment above. The issue is resolved by double-clicking on the database connector and selecting the "Refresh Metadata" link as described above.